# Mismatch Between the Parameters of a Logistic Regression in R and My Computed Parameters

Tags: r, logistic, interpretation

By converting and by trying to interpret the parameters of a logistic regression ran in R, I just find them to be overestimated. Therefore I tried to compute them myself but I can not obtain the same values reported by the regression.

I used this web-page for computations:
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/odds_ratio.htm

Let say we only focus on the LagC parameter:

**Logistic Regression**

```
> model <- glmer(RepT2 ~ DistractorC1 + DistractorC2 + LagC + DistractorC1:LagC + DistractorC2:LagC + (LagC | Subject) + (1 | Item),
                data = DF,
                family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
> summary(model)

  Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
  (Intercept)       -0.81039    0.22040  -3.677 0.000236 ***
  DistractorC1       0.33129    0.06393   5.182  2.2e-07 ***
  DistractorC2       0.03436    0.10011   0.343 0.731467    
  LagC               2.09567    0.12725  16.469  < 2e-16 ***
  DistractorC1:LagC -0.21654    0.12770  -1.696 0.089932 .  
  DistractorC2:LagC -0.84018    0.20055  -4.189  2.8e-05 ***
```

Odds of the parameters:

```
> show(Odds <- exp(summary(model)$coefficients[,"Estimate"])

  (Intercept)      DistractorC1      DistractorC2              LagC DistractorC1:LagC DistractorC2:LagC 
    0.4446833         1.3927594         1.0349529         8.1308503         0.8052993         0.4316343
```

Probabilities of the parameters:

```
> show(P <- Odds / (1 + Odds))

  (Intercept)      DistractorC1      DistractorC2              LagC DistractorC1:LagC DistractorC2:LagC 
    0.3078068         0.5820725         0.5085881         0.8904812         0.4460752         0.3014976
```

**My Estimations**

```
> Means <- DF %>%
    group_by(Subject, Lag) %>%
    filter(RepT1 == 1) %>%
    summarise(repok = sum(RepT2) / (n())) %>%
    group_by(Lag) %>%
    summarise(Means = mean(repok))

> show(Means)

     Lag     Means
  (fctr)     (dbl)
1   Lag3 0.1972174
2   Lag8 0.5475624
```

Odds of the parameter:

```
> OddsLag3 <- 0.1972174 / (1-0.1972174)
> OddsLag8 <- 0.5475624 / (1-0.5475624)
> OddsLagC <- OddsLag8 / OddsLag3
> show(OddsLagC)

[1] 4.926377
```

Probabilities of the parameter:

```
> show(OddsLag / (1 + OddsLag))

[1] 0.8312628
```

We can see that it is close, but not accurate. Does anyone have an explanation?
Note that I compute a mean for each subject and then only a mean for each condition. I also did estimate the parameters without taking into account the subjects, but still, the mismatch was here.

[Graphical representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRdPf.png)

Comment: It looks like you have two different models. LagC appears in the `glmer` version, along with several interactive effects, which do not appear in the hand-cranked version. Different models with different specifications will have different parameter estimates, even if you're performing the estimation correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I did not suspect there could be such a difference.